# return message/variable with Action Result Partial View to the success of an Ajax call

Tags: .net, ajax

I am making an ajax call to a method in my controller.  The method returns a Partial View ActionResult back to the success method in the ajax call.  I want to pass an additional message or variable to that success message so I can check for something.
Here is my current javascript ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("_AddToCart", "Cart")',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    qty: quantity
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    var cartLink = $(".add").attr("data-url");
                    $("#summary").html(response);
```

I am setting the HTML of a div to the entire response.  How can I pass an additional message or variable from the controller back to the success function?

Comment: Would it work to use ViewData?  Can I read that in my Javascript?

Comment: Try adding data in ViewData and access it in javascript. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374707/how-to-access-viewdata-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

- You could include some JavaScript in the partial view that runs when added to the DOM.  That JavaScript could be rendered in your partial using ViewData.
- Depending on the size of the data you want to pass around, you could also use a custom HTTP header.  This would be set on the server in your action, and read on the client in JavaScript:  [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Hope this helps!