# How to Pre populate drop down

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have the Drop down list which is populated from a GetJSON call as shown below

**VIEW**

```
@{
   var NoticeFilter =(X.Models.Y.Z.NoticesEntity) ViewData["NoticeFilter"];
}


<div class="form-group">
    <label>Field Office</label>
    <select  data-bind="options: FieldOffice, value: selectedFieldOffice, optionsCaption:'Choose...', optionsValue:'FieldOfficeID', optionsText:'Name'">
        @if(NoticeFilter!=null)
        {
            <option value="@NoticeFilter.FieldOfficeID" selected></option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

When I direct to this page and send data into the **NoticeFilter** I want  the value in  drop-down pre-selected with the value in **Noticefilter** among the other values .How do I achieve this

I was wondering if there is way in razor HTML where I can set a default value to Drop-Down after the data-binding from KO JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WORKING**
After few attempts I found this as one way to access the ViewData or ViewBag in my JS

I used the KO JS optionsAfterRender as below

VIEW

```
<select  data-bind="options: SubType, value: selectedSubType, optionsValue:'SubTypeID', optionsText:'SubTypeDescription',optionsAfterRender:function(){setOptionST(@Noticefilter .SubTypeID);}"></select>
```

**JS**

In the view model

```
 self.setOptionST = function (x) {
        //here we can do whatever is intended to in my case to set the initial value in dropdown
        self.selectedSubType(x);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<script>
var str = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Text"]));
</script>
```

Comment: I cannot use this as I am using Knockout JS in order to bind data to the drop down hence the issue.

Comment: just add the data-bind into the object htmlattribute section of that razor statement.  "@data_bind" is "data-bind"

Comment: But is this going to work cause I dont have a model initialized for the view and Noticefilter  is null most of the time.

Comment: Okay ignore my current answer but how about calling the list with ajax into js then appending the options with jquery ?

Comment: I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266755/how-to-pass-viewdata-from-controller-to-my-js

Comment: Here I try to send the List to JS via VIEWDATA but unable to do that

Comment: look at my answer again and tell me if you tried that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78230/discussion-between-imgreg-and-sss111).